# Not able to render state using componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs

I am getting props from parent component and trying to render

From parent component, I am passing the headings

Parent Component:

```
class CoreCloudServices extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      services:[]
    }
  }
  loadData(){
    var url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ftfdx";
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(d => {
        this.setState({ services: d });

      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }
 render(){
    <StatusFrame headings={this.state.services}/>
 }
```

Child Component:

```
class StatusFrame extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      labelHeading : this.props.headings
    }
  }

 componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)
    {
      this.setState({labelHeading: newProps.headings} , ()=>{
        console.log(this.state.labelHeading);
      });
    }
render(){
 return(
  <div>
    <div>
      {
        this.state.labelHeading.map(((head, index) => {
            <div>child {head.title}</div>
          })
        )
      }
      </div>
  </div>
)}}
```

this.state.labelHeading is null but I am setting the state in componentwillreceiveprops()

Comment: everything looks ok

Comment: why you wont just use this.props.headings without using the state

Comment: @Ali I am updating the props from parent component. and trying to update state in componentWillReceiveProps but not able to render

Comment: @Bhawna checkout my answer , it will help you

Comment: @Ali this.props.headings is null at the first time.

Comment: @Bhawna checkout my answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use the props without using the state , and you must return  from your parent render method , also in map callback you should return too

```
class CoreCloudServices extends React.Component{

    //...

   render(){
      return (<StatusFrame headings={this.state.services}/>)
   }
}




class StatusFrame extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
         super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    {
                        this.props.headings !== null ? 
                        this.props.headings.map(( (head, index) => 
                        {
                            return <div>child {head.title}</div>
                        }))
                        :
                        null
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check this comment: I am updating the props from parent component. and trying to update state in componentWillReceiveProps but not able to render

Comment: yes when the props changes the render method will triggered

Comment: No it is null in the initial, let me share the parent component with you. Check my edit

Comment: The props.heading is null

Comment: ahhh in your parent component you forget to return from render method , checkout the edit

Comment: that was by mistake. I forgot to copy it here

Comment: checkout this https://gist.github.com/turathalanbiaa/60f62395ea4216e0fd13695f6f0d0214

Comment: I was missing the return statement